# Xskak, command \setfen[]: no update of the board

Tags: chessboard, xskak, skak

I have the following solo chess example created with `\setfen[]`:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{xskak, longtable} % Schach
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false,}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
    \newgame
    \mainline{1.Nd5 Bd5} \chessboard[setfen=8/8/8/3p4/1N2r3/8/b5N1/8/]
    &
    \mainline{2.Ne4 Be4} 
    \chessboard
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The output of the second board is just a normal board of a new game, so it don't update the moves.
[image: output]

Did I do something wrong?

Another question I have is, can I show the board after every color move? So white-move, show board, black-move, show board.... When `\mainline{}` just get's one move I get an error.

Comment: tabular cells build groups. Better try first without longtable. And you can insert half moves \mainline{1. e4} \mainline{1... e5}.

Comment: Oh and you don't start a game with chessboard, use newchessgame to set a fan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for these tips, that helped me! I did it without longtable, but the second board is still a new one without the fen positions. I have: ```\newchessgame
\mainline{1.Nd5} \chessboard[setfen=8/8/8/3p4/1N2r3/8/b5N1/8/]
\mainline{1... Bd5}
\chessboard```

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got it, ```\fenboard{}``` do the job for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at first you are not setting the position with `\chessboard`, that only prints it. You should use `\newchessgame`.

At second you must be aware that the underlying `skak` package which executes the moves has some notion about the chess rules. It will not necessarely complain if you make moves that violates them (e.g. a black piece can take another black piece) but the resulting positions can sometimes be a bit surprising if you go against its assumptions.

For example in the first game below the move Nd5 is properly executed, but in the second not. This looks quite odd but the reason is that there are no kings on the board (which is against the chess moves) and so the code assumes the white king is on the start position (e1). This means that the black rook gives a check and the knight is not allowed to move.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false,}
 \newchessgame[setfen=8/8/8/3p4/1N3r2/8/b5N1/8]
 \chessboard
 \mainline{1. Nd5}
 \chessboard 

 \newchessgame[setfen=8/8/8/3p4/1N2r3/8/b5N1/8]
 \chessboard
 \mainline{1. Nd5}
 \chessboard 

\end{document}
```

[image]